# Gulp - globs - how to run sass function on all files in the folder EXCLUDING ONE?

Tags: gulp

I am a newcomer to Gulp. I have a gulp file and I am running one task in it -

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/scss/**/.scss') // Get source files with gulp.src
    .pipe(sass()) // Sends it through a gulp plugin
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css')) // Outputs the file in the destination folder
});
```

in the above code what i want to do is:
I have four scss files in app/scss folder:

1. site1.scss
2. site2.scss
3. site3.scss
4. copy.scss

Now i want to run the sass task and have all the files in scss folder excuding one particular file 'copy.scss'. I don't want the 'copy.scss' file to be converted into css file.

How do I do it?

Any help would be apprecisted

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return gulp.src(['app/scss/**/*.scss', '!app/scss/**/copy.scss'])
```

Note the ! It allows you to negate or remove from the stream a file or files.  Also note I added a * to your *.scss

Comment: You may wish to accept the answer as correct if it worked for you.  So others know the answer does work.  Thanks.